# Camel - Catch thrown exception in Global onException

Tags: java, spring, exception, apache-camel

I am trying to catch my own exception in the global onException. I have thrown my Exception after a Jaxb exception was caught. However the CustomException does not get caught by the onException

```
onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .log("Globally Caught CustomException") 
    .end();

from("start:direct")
    .doTry()
        .unmarshal(soapMessage)
    .doCatch(JAXBException.class)
        .log("Locally Caught JAXBException")
        .throwException(new CustomException()
    .endDoTry();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/try-catch-finally.html (see section **Camel error handling is disabled**), when using `doTry .. doCatch .. doFinally` Camel Error Handler doesn’t apply. Thus, any `OnException` is not triggered.

If you wanted to catch the exception with the `OnException` you should throw it directly and not inside a `DoTry .. DoCatch`. Now you might think to create two `onException`, one that handles the `Exception.class` and one that will handle the `JAXBException.class`.

```
onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log("Globally Caught CustomException")
            .end();
onException(JAXBException.class)
            .handled(true)
            .throwException(new CustomException())
            .end();
```

But again the first `onException` will not be called, because **Camel doesn’t allow further error handling while already handling an error**. This is done by the `org.apache.camel.processor.FataFallbackErrorHandler`, which catches the new exception, logs a warning, sets this as the exception on the Exchange, and stops any further routing (Camel In Action, second edition).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, i just modified your code to reproduce it seems working:

```
 onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(true)
            .log("Globally Caught CustomException")
            .end();

    from("timer://simpleTimer?period=1000")
            .setBody(simple("Timer at ${header.firedTime}"))
            .to("direct:demo");

    from("direct:demo")
            .doTry()
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        throw new JAXBException("Some Exception");
                    }
                })
            .doCatch(JAXBException.class)
            .log("Locally Caught JAXBException")
            .throwException(new CustomException())
            .endDoTry();
```

Log output: 
[image]

Comment: I dont understand how your code is any different to mine. Instead of marshalling, you add a process. So i can successfully catch the Jaxb exception and throw my own exception however it is not being caught by the onException.

Comment: Sorry, I only saw your log output now. Mine is still not working. Which version of camel are you using?

Comment: My apache came dependency version is 2.21.1

Comment: I used following code repo to modify and run the above posted code:  https://github.com/jinternals/camel/tree/master/file-copy